# I can not open Openshot in Ubuntu 17.04. What is the problem? how can I solve it?

Tags: openshot

I have removed it and and again installed, but still it is not working. When I try to open it, it blinks few seconds and automatically close.

Comment: Can you try opening it from the command line and post any error message you get.

Comment: Please do as Panther says. It is difficult/imposible to help you without further information

Comment: Hi,
I am assuming you've done the following: 

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install openshot-qt`

Comment: Yeah, I have done these. The software is there in the system. When I try to open by clicking it, It blinks but not opening. May I know the what is the command to open Openshot?
I am new to Ubuntu. I don not know much about it...

Comment: This problem is still in Ubuntu 18.04